# Snap points to linestring in Postgis

Tags: postgresql, gps, postgis

This code snap line to points. Any ideas how to modify the code to snap the points to line. Thanks.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_gps_point2;
SELECT D.ordinality As sub_id, D.geom::geometry(LINESTRING,3414) AS 
geom INTO test_table
FROM
gtd1304_line_2a AS L
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(  -- form a multipoint of all the nodes
   -- close enough to line to be considered on the line
    SELECT
        ST_Union(N.geom ORDER BY L.matched_line <-> N.geom) AS geom
    FROM gtd1304_point_2 AS N
    WHERE ST_DWithin(L.matched_line, N.geom, 10000)
) AS MP ON TRUE
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
-- snap the LINE to the MP which forces nodes to be injected to the line
-- then split at these node location and dump multilinestring into individual lines
ST_Dump(
     COALESCE(ST_Split(ST_Snap(MP.geom, L.matched_line, 10), matched_line), MP.geom)
    ) WITH ORDINALITY AS D;
```

Comment: I tried to run a provided query and I am getting following error: "[XX000] ERROR: Splitting of MultiPoint geometries is unsupported". What kind of point geometry are you inserting?
You might move your question to https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And your query could be simplify to something like that:

SELECT st_snap(geom, (SELECT st_collect(geom) geom FROM points), 10000) geom, chunk_id
  FROM lines;

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot do that, at least not with ST_Snap. I think the reason is that since you snap something A onto something B and get back something of type A with B snapped on it, and you can't get back something of type point with something snapped on it since then it becomes a line.